# Follow the path of relation through the grid #1

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path only once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Comment: lower right number is hard to spot: it is 25.

Comment: @daw Thanks for the clarification. I'll pick another colour in the future.

Comment: Gur erdhverzrag gung nqwnprag ahzoref or pbcevzr erfgevpgf gur tevq dhvgr avpryl, ohg vg nccrnef gb or n erq ureevat abarguryrff.

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem Lrf, naq V znqr n [eryngrq chmmyr](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3) gung qverpgyl hfrf aba-pbcevznyvgl.

Comment: Any more hints?

Comment: @CulverKwan Not sure I can give any more hints without it being the answer itself, but I'll think more on what hints I could give.

Answer (score 1):

I believe

> Every pair of numbers have no common factors (other than 1). So they are co-prime. Hopefully I haven't made a mistake...
>  [image]

Comment: [rot13](https://rot13.com/) (Fdhnerf ner abg cneg bs gur eryngvba, ohg gung vf na vagrerfgvat nccebnpu. Pbby.)

Comment: Base64(VG9wIGxlZnQ6IDc1ICYgODggYXJlIGNvcHJpbWUgLCBhbmQgODggJiA0NSBhcmUgY29wcmltZSBhcyB3ZWxsLCBzbyB0aGUgcGF0aCBpc24ndCB1bmlxdWUgaWYgdGhlIHJlbGF0aW9uIGlzIGNvcHJpbWFsaXR5Lg==)

Comment: Path is not unique with this relation.