# Follow the path of relation through the grid #2

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction, number-theory

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path only once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path is follows

> [image]

And the relationship is

> Two numbers on the path are adjacent if and only if they are both even.
>  The path is unique under this requirement.