# Follow the path of relation through the grid #3

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction, number-theory

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path only once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the relation is

> not coprime, i.e. having a common divisor > 1

Example:

> 31 is connected to 93 because gcd(93,31) = 31 > 1
> 93 is connected to 9 because gcd(93, 9) = 3 > 1
> 93 is not connected to 56 because gcd(93, 56) = 1

And the path is:

> [image]