# Follow the path of relation through the grid #4

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3)

Comment: dang, this is the fourth already? :000

Comment: @oAlt Too soon?

Comment: nope, all good :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path is as follows

> [image]

And the relationship is

> Adjacent numbers in the path differ by 1