# Follow the path of relation through the grid #5

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction, number-property

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-4)

Hint 1

> The relation is inspired by a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/about) puzzle.

Hint 2

> The relation pertains to whether adjacent numbers are part of the same triplet.

Comment: Care posting another hint?

Comment: @Daniil Sure, I'll add another soon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path is as follows

> [image: Solution Image]

And the relationship is

> Adjacent numbers are two members of a Pythagorean triplet

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I did not see that someone posted an answer already.

> [image: 1]

The relationship

> The sum or difference of squares of the connected numbers is a square.