# Follow the path of relation through the grid #6

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction, word-property, number-property

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-4)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98104/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this time the path is as follows

> [image]

And the rule is as follows

> Two numbers are adjacent on the path if they have the same number of letters in their English spelling (which is nine in all cases). Under this condition, the path is unique.