# Follow the path of relation through the grid #7

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction, primes

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-4)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98104/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-5)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98125/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-6)

Hint 1

> Closely-related to [Follow the path of relation through the grid #8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98203/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-8) .

Comment: Can you give a hint?

Comment: @CulverKwan Yeah, I'll add one soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> [image]

Reason

> Each numbers' *total* prime factors are exactly **4**. F ex: 90 is 2*3*3*5; 36 is 2*2*3*3; 88 is 2*2*2*11..... etc

Comment: Very fitting that you solved this!

Comment: I felt honored ;P