# Follow the path of relation through the grid #8

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction, primes

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-4)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98104/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-5)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98125/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-6)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path is as follows

> [image: Solution image]

And the relationship is

> Numbers in path are primes or prime powers. Put another way, numbers in adjacent squares both have the same number (1) of distinct prime divisors.

Comment: rot13(Gur vagraqrq eryngvba jnf gung gjb nqwnprag fdhnerf unq gur fnzr aba-qrtrarengr pbhag bs cevzr snpgbef, ohg lbhe eryngvba vf n fbyhgvba sbe guvf tevq!) Congratulations!

Comment: rot13(V'z purevgnoyl nffhzvat lbh zrnag gung nqwnprag fdhnerf ubyq gur eryngvba bs obgu univat gur nsberzragvbarq cebcregl, ohg na rqvg jbhyq or nccerpvngrq.)

Comment: That's great, thanks!