# Follow the path of relation through the grid #9

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction

There is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image]

Previous

- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98062/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-1)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98063/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-2)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98064/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-3)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-4)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98104/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-5)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #6](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98125/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-6)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #7](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98149/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-7)
- [Follow the path of relation through the grid #8](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98203/follow-the-path-of-relation-through-the-grid-8)

Comment: This is an easy one!

Comment: Then could you accept my answer :)

Comment: Yup, there's a countdown before I can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relation:

> All connected numbers are primes.

The path:

> [image]